# Lightning Components: DOM-Functions behave different on new vs. existing record

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, flexipages

**Scenario**

I've got a very simple component as described in detail below. It's height is about 19px. If I press on "Click Me", it should log it's height to the console (using vanilla JS). The compo is sitting on Account's Flexipage.

Now, when I use it on an existing account, it works as expected. But if I use it on an account, which is just created (click new button, see green toast on top), this component reports an height of 0px. If I press F5 and reload the page, it works again as expected.

**This example is perfectly reproducible.**

How this can be fixed, so that it works after record-creation, too?

**Expected behavior**

[image]

**Strange behavior**

[image]
**Markup**:

```
<aura:component access="global"  
        implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" 
>
    <aura:attribute name="name" type="String" default="VFContainer" access="global" />
    <ui:button label="Click me" press="{!c.test1}"  />
    <div id="te2" style="border: red solid 4px;">
        {!v.name}
        <br/>       
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Controller**:

```
({
    test1 : function(cmp,evt,hlp) {
        console.log(' vanilla h=', document.getElementById( "te2" ).clientHeight );
    },
})
```

**Design**:

```
<design:component label="trial u2">
    <design:attribute name="name"               label="Name"                description="Name" />
</design:component>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('te2').getBoundingClientRect()` is also coming back all 0's..

Comment: @Uwe Heim What happens if you use cmp.find() instead of document.getElementById()

Comment: @MohithShrivastava , it looks like it works if you use `cmp.find('te2').getElement()` instead of `document.getElementById( "te2" )`

Comment: But this is a Salesforce-bug and it doesn't work as it should, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because there are actually 2 instances of your div/component in the DOM tree after a new Account is created.

If you change your `div` to have `class="te2"` instead of an `id` and then in your click handler do:

`var te2 = document.getElementsByClassName("te2");`

You'll get back an array with both elements. The first element has `clientHeight` 0 because it is not visible (what you get back when you do your original `getElementById`), while the 2nd has the expected 19. I assume the first element is also not a valid component and thus not returned by `cmp.find().getElement()`, which would explain why Mohith's answer also works.

Originally, the copy of part of the DOM tree was kept around to support back button functionality but at this point it brings about such hard to track down differences in functionality like this that I would have to agree that it would probably be considered more of a bug than implementation detail.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, for now I'll try to use distinct class names instead of ids. Then also jquery should work as expected when I use $(".te2") instead of $("#te2"), right? That verbose vanilla notation is just a pain in my eyes and I used it only to rule out a jquery issue

Comment: Yes the jQuery APIs should still work.

Comment: With `id` at least jquery does not work - but I'll give `class` a try. If that's working I can live with the situation. However if there is no fix coming soon, I would recommend to put that into the documentation, because if you encounter those issues it might burn hours or even days of working time...

Answer (score 6):

```
cmp.find("te2").getElement()
```

I would use cmp.find() instead of document.getElement(). This is because cmp.find() is the native Lightning API for finding the DOM

To make this work, you have to add an `aura:id` like this to the `div`

```
<div aura:id="te2" id="te2">...</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot so far. I spimpyfied that example. In the real scenario im NOT using vanilla Javascript (because of it's ugliness and unreadable code in complex cases). I'm using jquery. Any idea how to teach jquery to use your workaround? But this is a Salesforce-bug, isn't it? The vanilla version should work, so that 3rd-party libs can operate correctly, right?

Comment: I agree with you on the bug .I will give a shot with jQuery as well

Comment: Great thanks. My idea would be to provide the crippled DOM as jquery needs them, but I suspect Locker Service will prevent us from doing so... so conditional hacking of jquery or going with vanilla JS seems to be the options. Both very bad...

Comment: unfortunately cmp.find("te2").getElement() gives me this: Uncaught Action failed: c$tryLC_u2$controller$test1 [Cannot read property 'getElement' of undefined

Comment: @UweHeim did you switch the `id` to `aura:id` on the `te2` div?

Comment: @martin thx, that was it... hell of a strangeness all that.